# Delete the longest consecutive series of characters from the front or the back

Tags: bash

For example a string has : aaaaabbaabaabbaa i want to trim it so that it deletes every "a" from the front until "b" so the result must be bbaabaabbaa.

Comment: theres no context here. there have been a lot of these lately, too, so sorry if i rant, but damn, man, what kind of question is this? its not even a question - you just say you want to do something. are you just letting us know? seriously, what string? how do you get it? where do you keep it? *why* do you keep it? put a little effort into the question if you want any kind of decent answer.

Comment: There's no question...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at the sections **Parameter Expansion** and **Pattern Matching** in `man 1 bash`:

```
$ shopt -s extglob # enable extended glob operators
$ s=aaaaabbaabaabbaa
$ echo "${s##*(a)}"
bbaabaabbaa

$ s=bananasssssssss
$ echo "${s%%*(s)}"
banana
```

Comment: Fails if the character inside parenthesis is `*` or ```\\```. Single quoting it will work: `s='bananass\\\\'; echo "${s%%*('\')}"`.

Answer (score 4):

With GNU `sed`:

```
sed -e 's/^\(.\)\1\{1,\}//'
```

that matches and deletes any character that repeats at least once at the beginning of a line.   it uses `^\(.\)` to match the first character, then `\1\{1,\}` to match 1 or more with back-reference to that match.

If you only want to match 1-or-more repeats of the first character, you could use just `sed -e 's/^\(.\)\1\+//'`, but the `\{1,\}` form can be easily modified for 2-or-more or 3-or-more etc if required.

Comment: the difference is, as i said, that the curly-brace form can easily be edited to be `{2,}` `{3,}` etc,  syntactic sugar - convenience not extra functionality.  without GNU you could do it as `\1\1\+` or `\1\1\1\+` etc.  which can quickly get ugly and difficult to read.

Comment: Got you now. The wording didn't make it very clear to me that you were talking of an alternative (note that it's non-standard) form. I see what you mean now.

Comment: sorry, i have limited typing abilty right now so my explanations are more terse than usual.  editing one-handed is hard.

Comment: `\(.\)\1\{2>,\}` is specified to work in a POSIX `sed`. its actually directly addressed in the specification.  The standard also addresses `/\(...\)\{2,\}/` and specs it to work, though that is best supported with a GNU `sed`. the standard way is with `[` bracket expressions `]` though.

Answer (score 1):

Just two lines:

```
$ a="aaaaabbaabaabbaaddd" 
$ echo "${a#"${a%%[^"${a:0:1}"]*}"}"
bbaabaabbaaddd
```

Action explained:

```
                  "${a:0:1}"         ## Select the first char of $a: ='a'
                [^          ]*       ## All chars not 'a' from the end. ='bbaabaabbaaddd'
          "${a%%              }"     ## Remove 'bbaabaabbaaddd' from the end of $a. ='aaaaa'  
echo "${a#                      }"   ## Remove 'aaaaa' from start of $a and echo it.
```

**(-)** Both Expansions need quotes to correctly deal with * and /.
There is still the issue that backquotes are usually incorrectly processed:

```
a="\\\\*\\\\*****vdf*"; echo "${a#"${a%%[^"${a:0:1}"]*}"}"
```

Will print:

```
*\\*****vdf*
```

The initial repeated string was correctly removed , but the next four backslash were transformed in just two.